# How to restore WhatsApp chat -- without a backup?

Tags: whatsapp-messenger

I have switched phones (both Android) and activated WhatsApp on the new phone.

Unexpectedly, the WhatsApp chat messages did not become available on the new phone and disappeared on the old one. I also had WhatsApp on my MacBook, where the old messages now also disappeared.

Unfortunately, I did not have a regular backup activated.

Is there anyway to restore access to the chat messages either from the MacBook or the old phone (whatever is easier/more reliable)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This may work, assuming you havent made drastic changes on your old phone. Whatsapp is linked to a phone number, so this is the side effect of it. I am basing this on seeing the same effect, when I  tried to run a second copy of Whatsapp on the same phone

1. Disable Whatsapp on new phone
2. Enable it back on the old one, the messages should come back.
3. Enable backup in Whatsapp setup
4. Wait for it to backup
5. Then switch over